# Show the curve $\alpha$ is differentiable and regular

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, plane-curves

> Consider the map:
>   $$
> \alpha(t) = \left\{
> \begin{array}{ll}
> (t,0,e^{-1/t^2}) & t>0 \\
> (t,e^{-1/t^2},0) & t<0 \\
> (0,0,0)          & t=0
> \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>
> a. Prove that $\alpha$ is a differentiable curve
>
> b. Prove that $\alpha$ is regular for all $t$.

This question is out of an old textbook, Riemannian Geometry of Curves and Surfaces, 1976. I believe the question is incorrect based on the definitions. As written, that curve is neither differentiable nor regular.

Could I get some justification of this and the statements of definitions from other sources? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you think it is neither differentiable nor regular?

Comment: What does "regular at $t$" mean? Maybe that the tangent vector is not the zero vector?

Comment: As expected you know that $e^{\frac{-1}{t^2}}$ is $C^\infty$ at zero. Perhaps it explain somethings.

Answer (score 2):

Denoting $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3)$, you have:

- $\forall t\in\mathbb{R}, \alpha_1(t)=t$;
- $\alpha_2(t)=e^{-t^2/2} \ \ \textrm{if} \ \ t<0$ else $\alpha_2(t)=0$;
- $\alpha_3(t)=e^{-t^2/2} \ \ \textrm{if} \ \ t>0$ else $\alpha_3(t)=0$.

It is a well-known fact that $\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ are smooth.

The first component $\alpha_1$ is clearly smooth and its derivative is $\alpha_1'\equiv 1$.
It follows that $\alpha$ is a smooth curve and that its derivative $\alpha'$ does not vanish. The second statement means that $\alpha$ is regular.